# How to use keyboard activation of the CheckComboBox

Tags: javafx-8, controlsfx

We have added a CheckComboBox to our window.  We populate it this way:

```
categoriesCheckComboBox.getItems().setAll(items);
```

This control is working for our needs except we can't seem to activate it with the keyboard.  Using a normal combobox, we can activate it with the arrowkey by pressing down.  This doesn't seem to work on this control.  Also it doesn't appear that it allows selection via the keyboard as well.

We are attempting to get this working for accessibility reasons.

Is there a setting I am missing to activate it that way?

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected working? A normal combobox on Up and Down keypress changes its selection which shall (can) not happen in case of CheckCombobox. A normal ComboBox displays its list when you press (on WIndows) Alt+Down - this is the same for CheckComboBox. Then you can navigate with Up - Down - it is also the same. For CheckBoxes inside you can navigate with Tab then when you press Space the CheckBox is selected. Please specify what keyboard shortcuts you want to have.

Comment: Thanks - I think I can work with those key combinations.